# How to make the best out of the Samsung Galaxy SIII camera application

Tags: camera, front-camera, camera-flash

Where can I find some good documentation concerning how to use the
features of the camera application installed on the Samsung Galaxy SIII
and how these features work under-the-hood? I would like to improve my
shots taken with the cameraphone.

Thanks.

Comment: [This blog](http://thegalaxys3gallery.blogspot.sg/2012/06/guide-samsung-galaxy-s3-camera-usage.html) seems to explain the camera quite detailed. Otherwise, look into [S3 manual](http://www.galaxys3manual.com/), from page 69.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something more in-depth. Thanks.